# remove all variables except functions

Tags: r, caching

I have loaded in a R console different type of objects.
I can remove them all using

```
rm(list=ls())
```

or remove only the functions (but not the variables) using

```
rm(list=lsf.str())
```

My question is:
is there a way to remove all variables except the functions

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Here's a one-liner that removes all objects *except for* functions:

```
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), lsf.str()))
```

It uses `setdiff` to find the subset of objects in the global environment (as returned by `ls()`) that don't have mode `function` (as returned by `lsf.str()`)

Comment: If you also want to remove objects whose names start with a period, use this instead:

`rm(list=setdiff(ls(all.names=TRUE), lsf.str(all.names=TRUE)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. May I know what is a period?

Comment: Sure. A period (in American English) is another name for a dot, like this: `.` To see what I'm talking about, try `.j <- 5; ls(); ls(all.names=TRUE)`

Comment: great, thank you. I already noticed that .j was not affected by ls() but could explain that.

Answer (score 7):

The posted `setdiff` answer is nice.  I just thought I'd post this related function I wrote a while back.  Its usefulness is up to the reader :-).

```
lstype<-function(type='closure'){ 
    inlist<-ls(.GlobalEnv)
    if (type=='function') type <-'closure'
    typelist<-sapply(sapply(inlist,get),typeof)
    return(names(typelist[typelist==type]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that. It makes for an interesting comparison with the code for `ls.str()` which, however, tests the `mode` rather than the `typeof` of objects. (On a side note, I'll be darned if I can figure the difference between those two from their documentation).

Comment: I always use class instead of typeof

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to clear out ALL variables. Be careful because it you cannot get your variables back.

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
```

Comment: Good to know but that's not the not the question

Comment: I guess I should have left that as a comment since it was more of an FYI. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty convenient function I picked up somewhere and adjusted a little.  Might be nice to keep in the directory.

```
list.objects <- function(env = .GlobalEnv) 
{
    if(!is.environment(env)){
        env <- deparse(substitute(env))
        stop(sprintf('"%s" must be an environment', env))
    }
    obj.type <- function(x) class(get(x, envir = env))
    foo <- sapply(ls(envir = env), obj.type)
    object.name <- names(foo)
    names(foo) <- seq(length(foo))
    dd <- data.frame(CLASS = foo, OBJECT = object.name, 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dd[order(dd$CLASS),]
}

> x <- 1:5
> d <- data.frame(x)
> list.objects()
#        CLASS       OBJECT
# 1 data.frame            d
# 2   function list.objects
# 3    integer            x 
> list.objects(env = x)
# Error in list.objects(env = x) : "x" must be an environment
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to remove all objects apart from functions from the current environment (Programming language used is R with IDE R-Studio):

```
    remove_list=c()                             # create a vector

      for(i in 1:NROW(ls())){                   # repeat over all objects in environment
        if(class(get(ls()[i]))!="function"){    # if object is *not* a function
         remove_list=c(remove_list,ls()[i])     # ..add to vector remove_list
         }    
      }

    rm(list=remove_list)                        # remove all objects named in remove_list
```

Notes-

The argument "list" in rm(list=) must be a character vector.

The name of an object in position i of the current environment is returned from ls()[i] and the object itself from get(ls()[i]). Therefore the class of an object is returned from class(get(ls()[i]))

Comment: Please add more information about "current environment", e.g. whether this is shell or certain programming language