# Clean environment to speed up function in R

Tags: r, removeall

I have this example data and some example functions

```
other_data<-c(1,2,3) # data I have to have
fun<-function(a,b,c){
data<-c(a,b,c)
return(data)
} # first function

var_1<-runif(20,10,20) # variables
var_2<-runif(20,10,20)
var_3<-runif(20,10,20)

vars<-data.frame(var_1,var_2,var_3) # data frame of variables
subfun<-function(x){
res<-fun(vars[x,1],vars[x,2],vars[x,3])
return(res)
} # sub function of the first one to use more options and get them into list

final<-lapply(c(1:nrow(vars)),subfun) # this should be the final result I want to get
```

The problem is, that my real data is much more bigger and I have about 500 "data" (like in first function) which has to be reloaded every time because of different values of `a,b,c`. And it seems to slow down the function because of memory, i.e. environment.
I don't want to do it like `rm(data)` and repeat it 500x times in first function before the row `return(data)`.
So my questions

Is there any straightforward way how to remove all objects which was loaded during the function, but only these objects in `fun(a,b,c)`? Because I need to DONT remove `other_data`.

Or more simply, is there straightforward way how to delete all objects like `rm(ls(),instead of=c("other_data")`?

Comment: To remove all objects except "other_data" you can do: `rm(setdiff(ls(), "other_data"))`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305754/remove-all-variables-except-functions or `setdiff(ls(), c(lsf.str(), "other_data"))` if you want to keep your custom functions too.

Comment: Or `rm(list=ls()[-which(ls()=="other_data")])` would also work

Comment: Think I should have written `rm(list = setdiff(ls(), c(lsf.str(), "other_data")))` to make it work properly.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work in my real case. Do you have any approaches how to speed up function when there has to be many loaded data (every step different) which takes a lot of memory and slow the function down, mainly if it has 10 000+ repetition?

Comment: I haven't fully understood the intention behind your code. Could you possibly load all the data into a list at once and the just use the different list elements in different repetitions?

Comment: I think your code should already be doing what you want. Variables defined in the body of a function go out of scope after that function returns, so for example the `data` and `res` variables should already be getting removed at the end of each function call. You could try calling `gc` between each function call to trigger the garbage collector, but I doubt that would make a huge difference.

Comment: By the way, applying over rows of a data frame is usually pretty inefficient and should be replaced with vectorized operations on columns if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to keep certain object you can use function keep from library gdata. http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gdata/docs/keep

```
library('gdata')
var1 <- 1
var2 <- 2

ls()
[1] "var1" "var2"

keep(var1, sure = T)    
ls()
[1] "var1"
```

Setting sure to True performs the removal. Otherwise keep will return names of objects that would have been removed.