# Function to remove all variables

Tags: r

From [remove all variables except functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305754/remove-all-variables-except-functions), I got the command to remove all variables without removing functions.  I don't want to type it in all the time, so I tried to turn it into a function defined in ~/.Rprofile.  I'm new to R, but I've browsed the environment frame scheme, and have a shaky understanding of it.  The following attempt doesn't seem to erase a time series object defined in the main environment (the command line prompt when I first start R):

```
# In ~/.Rprofile
clVar <- function()
{
    rm(
        list=setdiff( ls(all.names=TRUE), lsf.str(all.names=TRUE)),
        envir=parent.frame()
    )
}
```

The following code shows that it doesn't work:

```
( x<-ts( 1:100 ,frequency=12 ) )
clVar()
ls()
```

Thanks for any help in fixing the environment framing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the `parent.frame()` environment to `ls`, not just to `rm`. Otherwise `ls` won't find the variables to remove.

```
clVar <- function()
{
    env <- parent.frame()
    rm(
        list = setdiff( ls(all.names=TRUE, env = env), lsf.str(all.names=TRUE, env = env)),
        envir = env
    )
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out!  But thanks!  By the way, I can't seem to mark this response as an answer for another 5 minutes.  Strange why there would be a minimal time.

Comment: @user36800 Cool! Reason behind time limit is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste)

Comment: I never knew that ensuring quality on stack exchange could be so...thoroughly thought out.  Thanks.